# K-nearest neighbor with kernel gives me the exact same accuracy with different initial conditions (R,caret)

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour, caret

```
seeds_list <- list()
for (n in 1:47){
    seeds_list[[n]] <- sample(1:400)
}
library(kknn)
model <- train(Class~.,data = network_measures,method = 'kknn',
               trControl = trainControl(method = 'LOOCV',seeds = seeds_list),
               preProcess = c('center','scale'),
               tuneGrid = expand.grid( kmax = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), distance = c(1,2,3,4), kernel = c('rectangular','triangular','rank','gaussian',
                                                                                   'epanechnikov','biweight','triweight','cos',
                                                                                   'inv','optimal')))
```

Hello,

This code is part of a loop. In each loop I set a new seed number. But I still get the exact same accuracy, same k and even same kernel. This is very strange. Using a simple knn (method = "knn") I get some variation in the accuracy, which is to be expected. Is my code wrong or should I just give it more time?
Thanks!

Comment: knn shouldn't have any randomness, should it?

Comment: Before running an iteration I set a new seed. Using a regular KNN (no kernels) I get some variations, sometimes up to 10% depending on the seed. Maybe KNN with kernels is too powerful to be affected by seed changes, but I am not sure.